# How to get &T from Cell<T>

Tags: rust

I need to fork the popular [gc](https://crates.io/crates/gc) crate just to implement `Trace + Finalize` for `Cell`. That's how the library implements these for `Vec`:

```rust
impl<T: Trace> Finalize for Vec<T> {}
unsafe impl<T: Trace> Trace for Vec<T> {
    custom_trace!(this, {
        for e in this {
            mark(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to do the same with `Cell<T>`, but it only works if `T: Copy`. There's no `as_ref()` method in `Cell`, so how can I do it better?

```rust
impl<T: Trace> Finalize for Cell<T> {}
unsafe impl<T: Trace + Copy> Trace for Cell<T> {
    custom_trace!(this, {
        // this: &Cell<T>
        mark(&this.get());
    });
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't really get an `&T` from a `Cell<T>`. Perhaps you could try to `borrow()`, which returns a `Ref<'_, T>`?

Comment: @a3y3 Yeah, I've tried, `Borrow` is implemented for `Cell<T>`, but the return of `borrow()` is `&Cell<T>`.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the internals of `gc`, however I note it provides `GcCell<T>` which is essentially `RefCell<T>` *except* it implements `Trace`. This leads me to believe there might be something wrong about simply implementing `Trace` for `Cell<T>`. Are you sure this is sound?

Comment: (a3y3 is thinking of `RefCell`, not `Cell`. `RefCell::borrow` and `Borrow::borrow` are different functions)

Comment: @trentcl, yeah, you're right - my bad.

Comment: @trentcl The problem is, `GcCell` cannot mutate its value, only `Cell` can. Quote from crates.io: _Much like with Rc, to get mutability, we must use a cell type. The regular RefCell from the stdlib will not work with Gc (as it does not implement Trace), instead, use GcCell._

Comment: I'm not sure how you read that quote to mean "`GcCell` cannot mutate its value", since its API is basically the same as `RefCell`'s.

Comment: @trentcl I mean, `Cell` supports methods like `set()`. `RefCell` inner can be borrowed mutably, but can't `set()` its inner value.

Comment: `RefCell` doesn't need `set` because you can just assign to a dereferenced `RefMut`: `*cell.borrow_mut() = new_value` instead of `cell.set(new_value)`. But what I'm really wondering is why you believe this is sound. Reading about [why `GcCell` exists](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/09/01/designing-a-gc-in-rust/#mutability) suggests that implementing `Trace` for `Cell` would open you up to a similar problem as that outlined with `RefCell`.

Comment: @trentcl I didn't know about this assignment being valid, so using `GcCell` works. I didn't think it of being sound, I just thought it'd be easier to use `Cell` with a straight `set()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a `&T` from a `Cell<T>`. In fact, that's the whole point of `Cell`. Allow me to explain:

One of the core ideas of Rust is that aliasing and mutation happening at the same time is the source of all sorts of evils. Therefore `(multiple references (aliasing) & mutation)` must not happen in Rust. There are two special cases where we can exclude this situation:

- If there is exactly one reference, there can't be multiple references which alias. This is why `&mut T` exists. We call it "mutable reference" but the point here is that the compiler guarantees that it is a unique reference, preventing aliasing; we are free to mutate `T` in this case without worries. If we have a living `&T` the situation is reversed: aliasing is possible using `&T`, and mutation is prohibited.
- If there is exactly no reference, the same argument applies. This is the case for `Cell<T>`, which does not allow ever getting a `&T` from its inside (its a, well, cell). Since there are no references, we are free to mutate the value at any time, because there can't be any outstanding observers. This is why you can use an immutable reference to a `Cell<T>` to modify the `T` (e.g. `mycell.set(123)`).

These two special cases allow Rust to prevent aliasing & mutation at compile-time without too much hassle on the programmer.

As far as one can judge from your code-snippet, this is exactly the kind of situation a `Cell` must prevent: The `mark()` function takes `&T` and could possibly do anything with it, including storing it, passing it on, duplicating it or getting a reference to a member of `T`. A reference escaping into other scopes like this is prevented by `Cell`, allowing mutation without the "fear" of aliasing.

You might want to reconsider why there is a `Cell` in the first place. It might signal that *the value* of `T` must not escape at all because code elsewhere mutates the `T` and you are then using stalled/outdated values.

You might be able to use a `RefCell`, the bigger brother of `Cell`, which tracks aliasing/mutation at runtime using a proxy-type that manages all access. You *can* get a `&T` from a `RefCell`, but your implementation must guarantee that it never, ever tries to mutate while aliasing (which the compiler can't catch, but the runtime will, causing a panic).